# Filter a GroupBy Function in a Gallery in Power Apps

Tags: filter, sum, gallery, powerapps, group

I have a gallery using the following GroupBy Function:

GroupBy(
tbl_TimeCard,"Employee","DATA")

and a Sum Function for the total hours based on the employee

Sum(Filter(tbl_TimeCard,Employee=ThisItem.Employee),TotalHours)

Results:

| Employee | Total Hours |
| --- | --- |
| Cathy Lewis | 35 |
| Arnold Lemmons | 40 |
| Tony Jones | 28 |

I would like to Filter the Results by using the following:

Filter(
tbl_TimeCard,TotalHours < 40)

Question: How can I combine the GroupBy and Filter Function to achieve this?

Desired Output:

| Employee | Total Hours |
| --- | --- |
| Cathy Lewis | 35 |
| Tony Jones | 28 |

Answer (score 0):

**Updated based on comments**:

This is just something quick so you can play around with the following:

```
ClearCollect(colNewTable, ShowColumns(tbl_TimeCard, "Employee", "TotalHours"));
```

You can either group it here or afterwards, I'm going with before as an example:

```
ClearCollect(colGrouped, GroupBy(colNewTable, "Employee", "DATA"));
```

Now adding a column back with a sum of hours, note there is no . after `colGroup` and `[@Employee]`

```
ClearCollect(colFinal, AddColumns(colGrouped, "TotalHoursSum", 
    Sum(Filter(colNewTable, Employee = colGrouped[@Employee] ), TotalHours)));
```

You should now be able to filter `colFinal`

**Previous Answer:**

It may be easier if you create a collection first and use that (possibly quicker as well).

Create the collection on app start or loading the page etc:

```
ClearCollect(colTimeCardGrouped, GroupBy( tbl_TimeCard,"Employee","DATA"));
```

Then you can go wild filtering the collection, ie:

```
Filter(colTimeCardGrouped, TotalHours < 40)
```

Comment: Since the Collection was groupby the "Employee", it won't let me Filter the collection by the TotalHours

Comment: Updated with another possible solution. Let me know if it works.

Comment: When I Filter on colFinal, it returns all three records and does not exclude the record with the total hours of 40     Filter(colFinal,Value(TotalHours.Text)<40)

Comment: You shouldn't be able to do TotalHours.Text, unless you have done something different. Filter(colFinal, AddedSumColumn < 300) works well for me on my data set. In saying that I have found one error above, which I'll fix and comment on.